# How to customize build decision logic for phony targets, that doesn't involve files

Tags: python, scons

I have a target, that requires some time-expensive actions and depends on similar time-expensive targets. It's also a phony target, so it doesn't depends on a source files nor it doesn't produces a files. And I want to make SCons decide when to build this target or not depending on some abstract value.

To me it would be ideal to use the capability of SCons, [described in the manual](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#f-Value) as:

> `Value(value, [built_value]) , env.Value(value, [built_value])`
>
> ... Value Nodes can be used as dependencies of targets. If the result of calling str(value) changes between SCons runs, any targets depending on Value(value) will be rebuilt. ...

So I've build this SConstruct to test it:

```
import random as rnd


env = Environment()


def action(**_):
    print('Do crazy things')

input = env.Value('a')

env['BUILDERS']['Custom'] = Builder(action=action)
env.Custom(target='target', source=input)
env.Pseudo('target')
```

And I expected SCons to stop rebuilding the target after the first build, since the value of the input Value remains constant between builds. But SCons rebuilds it every time.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm talking about?

Comment: You can also see related responses in the SCons users mailing list here as the author also posted the question there: https://pairlist4.pair.net/pipermail/scons-users/2016-March/004756.html

Comment: What does it consume, and what does it produce?  A concrete answer would help to provide a reasonable solution.